# Correct tense after I come to a country

Tags: tense, past-tense

Imagine I go to another country on a vacation to visit my friends. When I talk to the local people, should I say:

> "I **come** here to visit my friends"

or

> "I **came** here to visit my friends"

Also, if this is the first time I visit that country, should I say:

> "This is the first time I **came** here"

or:

> "This is the first time I **come** here"

Comment: "I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him". Very formal, quite old-fashioned. Used for announcing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would suggest that if you visit England every summer to visit your friends, you should say "I come here to visit my friends," meaning that you do so regularly. If you do not go routinely but you're there now, you could say "I came here to visit my friends."
2. On your first visit you should say "This is the first time I have come here," not "This is the first time I come here."